# Cargar csv a postgressql mediante node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

estube buscando pero no encontre, queria saber como cargar un archivo csv a mi base de datos mediante node... Lo estoy haciendo por pg adming manualmente con un script, pero queria automatizar mi programa. El script que estoy haciendo en pg admin es el siguiente:

```
COPY PUBLIC.flights (YEAR,MONTH,DAY,DAY_OF_WEEK,AIRLINE,FLIGHT_NUMBER,TAIL_NUMBER,ORIGIN_AIRPORT,DESTINATION_AIRPORT,SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE,DEPARTURE_TIME,DEPARTURE_DELAY,TAXI_OUT,WHEELS_OFF,SCHEDULED_TIME,ELAPSED_TIME,AIR_TIME,DISTANCE,WHEELS_ON,TAXI_IN,SCHEDULED_ARRIVAL,ARRIVAL_TIME,ARRIVAL_DELAY,DIVERTED,CANCELLED,CANCELLATION_REASON,AIR_SYSTEM_DELAY,SECURITY_DELAY,AIRLINE_DELAY,LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY,WEATHER_DELAY)
    from 'rutadelarchivo\flights.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.!

Comment: No se de node.js, pero te sirve iniciar una conexion, creae un cursor y mandar el script publicado usando dicho cursor?

Comment: No entendi disculpa

Comment: No hay problema. Lo que propuse es conectarte a la base de datos usando node.js y mandar tu script usando esa conexion

Comment: Sería lo ideal pero no sé cómo hacerlo

Comment: Entonces, podrías averiguar como usando Google. Nosotros no damos guías ni recomendaciones. Si buscas eso, te recomiendo recurrir a otro sitio.